# GRUB triple boot trouble: Ubuntu + Windows XP + FreeDOS 1.2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, ms-dos

I am trying to make all the OSess bootable (Ubuntu + Windows XP + FreeDOS 1.2). FreeDOS cannot boot, it says about missing NTLDR and hangs the system.

Boot-info:

1. I tried installing FreeDOS 1.2 before XP and after XP. Neither helped.
2. After installation of XP i moved XP's boot files from sdc1 to sdc2 (XP is on sdc2, FD is on sdc1, Ubuntu on sdc3) and re-installed GRUB. XP boots well, but FDOS does not.

How to make FreeDOS 1.2 bootable?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

I discovered that Windows XP can load when bootloader is on a partition which is different from the partition where files of the OS are. I thought that FreeDOS is able to do same tricks, but it is not able to do so.

In other words, ntldr should be on both partitions and contents of boot.ini can not be identical on different partitions. 'boot.ini' on sdc1 can load both OS, and ntldr on sdc2 can load only XP, as FD does not allow such chain of calls.

In order not to rely strongly on GRUB i have made two instances of load files. Both sdc1 and sdc2 have the following set of files:

```
boot.ini, 
Bootfont.bin,
NTDETECT.COM,
ntldr.
```

The 'boot.ini' on /dev/sdc1 has contents:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional RU" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
C:\="FreeDOS 1.2"
```

The 'boot.ini' on /dev/sdc2 has contents:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional RU" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
```